# How to change "python manage.py" to "./manage.py"?

Tags: django, django-manage.py

I want to shorten `python manage.py` to `./manage.py`.

This may be simple, but I couldn't find an answer for this. I saw a step by step method in one of the answers for questions about django but I did not memorize that. Tried to search for answers on stackoverflow to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on a Unix based system:

Make sure the file has the proper shebang (=this line) as the topmost line (it should have this by default already):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Make your script executable by running:

```
$ chmod u+x manage.py
```

After that you're good to go.

Answer (score 2):

In order to do that, you will need to do two things:

1. define the proper [*shebang* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) in the `manage.py` file; and
2. make the file executable.

Normally the `manage.py` file already *has* a shebang at the top:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

but depending on your system this might invoke [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) instead of [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), you thus might want to change this to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

If you make use of a virtual environment, you should let this point to the python executable of the virtual environment instead, so:

```
#!path/to/env/bin/python3
```

Next you make the file executable, you can do this with `chmod`:

```
chmod +x manage.py
```

or if you only want to make it executable by the owner of the `manage.py` file, you can use:

```
chmod u+x manage.py
```