# Django’s command-line utility | manage.py: command not found

Tags: python, django, terminal

I'm new to Django and trying to use manage.py instead of django-admin command as Django's documentation mentioned (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/)

so from what I learned, I can use these interchangeably.

```
$ django-admin <command> [options]
$ manage.py <command> [options]
$ python -m django <command> [options]
```

So my problem is when I use manage.py , the terminal says:

```
manage.py: command not found
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Likely your `manage.py` is not executable. You can run this in the directory where `manage.py` is located of your Django project with `python3 manage.py <command> [options]`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it worked. thank you. Is there any way to make it executable? or Is there anywhere I can read more about it?

Comment: funny enough, that was asked less than an hour ago :) https://stackoverflow.com/q/65438996/67579

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
python manage.py runserver 8080
```

firstly, on your terminal search your Python version: `python --version`

Secondly, now you must have found the python version, in my case it is Python 3.11.2.

I will type:

```
python3.11 manage.py runserver 8080
```

In my case the problem has been resolved.

Comment: The wording here is a little unclear. It sounds like you're talking about path/version issue and that the asker should verify the `python` they are calling is the same version of python they installed the package for.